# What are features considerd as advanced python?

Tags: python

I do basic python programming and now I want to get deep into language features. I have collected/considered the following to be advanced python capabilities and learning them now.

1. Decorator
2. Iterator
3. Generator
4. Meta Class

Anything else to be added/considered to the above list?

Comment: IMHO, those are basic features of the language.  "Advanced" programming is using/writing complex, non-trivial libraries to do Real Work.

Comment: Its community wiki now. feel free to update..

Comment: It's amazing how you see people use all those features, and then reimplement stuff from say textwrap or itertools because they don't know the library all that well. Also knowing when to choose a list/set/array/heapq/deque seems to be difficult for some.

Comment: What does "advanced" mean?  "learn later"?  "Safely ignore?"  If it means learn later, then there's a complex spectrum of what to learn in what order.  If it means you can safely ignore this, then all implementation details fall into that category.  What does "advanced" mean?  What will you change or do differently based on something being called "advanced"?

Comment: "Advanced" isn't a very advanced word; try "features that have a significant level of prerequisite learning".  Partial template specialization is an advanced C++ feature.  Python simply doesn't have advanced features.  The whole language core is very simple.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: Thanks for your help.  I wonder what the original question meant by Advanced.  It's an open-ended thing that could have other interpretations than yours.  The example list, for example, doesn't seem to contain things that fit your definition of advanced.  I'm guessing the original question uses a different definition than yours.

Comment: He may have meant "advanced for a person learning his first language", which I suppose includes a lot more, but that doesn't make them "advanced Python topics".  *shrug*

Answer (score 2):

First, this thread should be community wiki.

Second, iterators and generators are pretty basic Python IMHO. I agree with you on decorators and metaclasses. But I'm not a very good programmer, so I probably find this more difficult to wrap my brain around than others.

Third, I would add threading/multiprocessing to the list. That's really tricky :)

Comment: Hey, I thought when a question is community wiki, the answers are too. Obviously not, so I changed my answer to cw, too.

Answer (score 2):

There are some useful core concepts that can be added to your list, and that I would not necessarily teach in an introductory Python class (from the most common to the more specific):

- the [various protocols](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) (sequence, iterator, context,…)
- [properties](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property)
- [packages](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Some points related to important standard modules:

- Making your classes compatible with the standard `copy` and `pickle` modules.

Answer (score 1):

The first 3 are intermediate Python, not advanced. For advanced add the stuff in the [Importing Modules](http://docs.python.org/library/modules.html) and [Python Language Services](http://docs.python.org/library/language.html) sections of the library reference.

Comment: I'm not sure if decorator and meta class is considered intermediate. We rarely use it in day to day programming unless we are making a framework.

Comment: "metaclass" is not part of the "first 3". It's definitely advanced, in that it's tricky to grasp, and easy to misuse.
I agree that decorator (as in writing them) IS intermediate. Maybe it's only required when making a framework, but any non-trivial app ends up making its own framework.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that there isn't a good answer to your question.  What's great about Python is that all of its features are fairly easy to understand.  But there's enough stuff in the language and the library that you never get around to learning it all.  So it really boils down to which you've had occasion to use, and which you've only heard about.

If you haven't used decorators or generators, they sound advanced.  But once you actually have to use them in a real-world situation, you'll realize that they're really quite simple, and wonder how you managed to live without them before.